# Trying to get my pool pump wired the RIGHT way

Tags: electrical, pool

I recently had my new above ground pool hard wired by a "So Called" electrician. My pump is 120v I found out that he wired 220v to it and almost burnt my pump up. Luckily I was there when he threw the switch and cut it off.. my pump still works, I just plug it to a regular receptacle.

- My question is?
  What circuit breaker do I need. I was told a 20amp Tandem GFCI breaker since my breaker box is full.
  Is this correct and is there anything else I need to do?

Comment: Can you post photos of your panel please?

Comment: Yes I will post pictures. But to clarify exactly what I have is, from pool pump backwards I have a GFCI receptacle at my pump that it plugs into which is capped /sealed, then that goes to a trimmer then to a disconnect then to my fuse panel inside my house. My problem is, is that it's connected to a 220 v breaker that also is connected to my outside building. I was told that it needs to be connected to a separate circuit with a 120v GFCI breaker at my panel. The thing is, my breaker is full. That's why they also said it needed to be a tandem breaker. So what do I do?

Comment: @RickHutchens if the panel is full then replace with a larger panel.

Comment: Many pool pumps can be internally wired to run at 120v or at 240v.  So you might be able to change the pump so it can run with the 240v that's available.  Depends on the pump manufacturer and model.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find a tandem (a.k.a., half-size/double-stuff) GFCI breaker. They don't exist.

A few different things are involved here:

- GFCI is an absolute must for anything around a pool, including pump, heater, lighting, etc. More on that below.
- You need a disconnect of some sort. If it is plug/receptacle then you can just pull the plug. Otherwise you need a disconnect (like an A/C disconnect - cheap and easy) or very commonly a subpanel (the breakers are a disconnect).
- If you have other stuff to power (heater, lights, convenience receptacles, etc.) then a subpanel makes a lot of sense.

GFCI can be provided at a feed breaker to a subpanel (e.g., a 50A (or whatever) double-breaker with GFCI in the main panel). That will protect everything connected to the subpanel. Or you can have individual breakers in a subpanel each with GFCI. Or for any 120V circuits you can use a GFCI/receptacle or a GFCI/deadfront (same size as GFCI/receptacle, but no receptacles).

There are major advantages to a GFCI being inside. However, a GFCI/deadfront could be very useful here if the *only* circuit involved is a 120V hardwired pool pump:

- Since it is 120V, GFCI/deadfront is an option instead of GFCI/breaker.
- By *not* having receptacles, you avoid someone overloading the circuit by plugging in other stuff at the same time the pump is running.
- Assuming the GFCI/deadfront is switch-rated, that should take care of any disconnect requirement. But it is worth double-checking that to be sure.

Comment: Yes I do have a GFCI RECEPTACLE BY MY PUMP THAT IT PLUGS INTO, PLUS I DO HAVE A Disconnect (I guess that what you call it) but it looks just like the same box that my A/C has. I also have a trimmer in-between the pump and the disconnect. The problem is, is that my fuse panel is full and my pool pump is connected to my outside building which is 220v. I was told that my pump needs to be on a separate 120v circuit. So how do I make room in my panel if they don't make a GFCI tandem breaker?

Comment: @RickHutchens  How is it connected to the outside building?  I assume you did not just have two hots wires at the building that you connected the pump to, but maybe a small panel.

Comment: No the so called electrician since I had no room in my main breaker panel in my house he hooked my pool pump on the same circuit as my outside building , not at my building to my pool pump

Comment: Do you know if this 240 volt circuit also has a neutral?